# Process content from database as php

Tags: php, eval

I'm not exactly sure what I need to search for in Google and have been struggling with this for a while.

I wrote my own CMS for a project and am stuck with processing content stored in the database, for example.

```
This is a link to a <a href="<?php get_url_by_id(487174) ?>">related page</a>.
```

In the above example I'm getting a page url by its ID, this way it doesn't matter if the url changes, it will always be up to date.

The issue is PHP sees it as a string and will not process it.

Im working around the issue by writing the contents to a file, using PHP include on the file, and then deleting the file. I don't see this as an efficient and would like a better solution.

Comment: Sees and processes `what`?

Comment: Where's the code of `get_url_by_id`?

Comment: <?php echo get_url_by_id(487174) ?> The code is not relevant to my question; It simply inserts the URL.

Comment: How are you getting the code from the database to be interpreted as PHP? However you decide to do it, some controlling of what PHP code is allowed to run from the the database, will be required?

Answer (score 1):

PHP reads that content as a string because *it is* a string.

To make your string function as PHP, you'll need to use PHP's `eval()` function.

```
// The string that is loaded from the DB, or wherever
$string = 'This is a link to a <a href="<?php get_url_by_id(487174) ?>">related page</a>.'

// Run the string as PHP code (notice the "echo" command)
eval("echo {$string}");
```

**This can be very dangerous, however!** If you're going to do this, be very certain you know what string is being executed! Because the `eval()` function will run any PHP code that is placed in it! Even site-destroying-dog-kicking PHP code!

More about the `eval()` function can be found in the [PHP Docs for eval()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php)

--

I don't know your exact scenario, but I would generally advise against using `eval()` wherever possible. There is normally a safer way to doing something than using the `eval()` function.

Comment: @PedroLobito You're referring to the PHP function that is being called **within** the string that is being pulled from the DB--which isn't being called at all because PHP interprets it as a string.

Comment: I'm referring to function `get_url_by_id`

Comment: @PedroLobito Yes, but that's irrelevant to the OP's question as well as my answer. `'This is a link to a <a href="<?php get_url_by_id(487174) ?>">related page</a>.'` is a string.

Comment: @PedroLobito why would that function be relevant? Do you even use PHP?

Comment: @PedroLobito - congratulations on making an immense contribution to solving someone's problem, don't forget to pat yourself on the back :)

Comment: exec is certainly not right. Ive also tried eval, but after a day of looking over everything I have decided to do a lot of refactoring and use a string replace function to insert hyperlinks into content.